How to Handle Product Schema When No Price is Available
One problem I’m facing, which many others are also struggling with and there isn’t a clear source to resolve it, is regarding products that don’t have a listed price (the product is available but the customer has to call for the price).
Yoast SEO automatically changes the schema from Product to WebPage in such cases. On the other hand, Rank Math keeps the schema as Product but doesn’t include a price field, which results in Google throwing errors.
Now, I’ve seen solutions like manually adding
"@type": "AggregateOffer",
"priceCurrency": "IRR",
"lowPrice": "0",
"highPrice": "0",
"offerCount": "0"

which is what websites like do.
I’m unsure which approach is the correct one, and I haven’t found any proper guidance on this issue. Can you provide some advice?

This question is similar to: Is product price required for schema.org markup?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can you use null?
